# Number of passengers. Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to sum the number of passenger at each stop.

The "stops" variable are the number of stops, and is conformed by a tuple which contains the in's and out's of passengers, example:

```
stops = [(in1, out1), (in2, out2), (in3, out3), (in4, out4)]
```

```
stops = [(10, 0), (4, 1), (3, 5), (3, 4), (5, 1), (1, 5), (5, 8), (4, 6), (2, 3)]
number_passenger_per_stop = []

for i in stops:
    resta = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1]
    number_passenger_per_stop.append(resta)
print(number_passenger_per_stop)
```

I can do the math like this outside the loop, but I don't understand why in the loop crashes:

`stops[i][0] - stops[i][1]`

Comment: Just for reference, it sounds like we're solving https://www.codewars.com/kata/number-of-people-in-the-bus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is not the list index, it's the list element itself. You don't need to write `stops[i]`.

```
resta = i[0] - i[1]
```

Your code would be correct if you had written

```
for i in range(len(stops)):
```

You could also replace the entire thing with a list comprehension:

```
number_passenger_per_stop = [on - off for on, off in stops]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the for loop to adress each in the index in the list correctly, you needed to call each element in the list by its position, and not by its value:

```
stops = [(10, 0), (4, 1), (3, 5), (3, 4), (5, 1), (1, 5), (5, 8), (4, 6), (2, 3)]
number_passenger_per_stop = []

for i in range(len(stops)):
    resta = stops[i][0] - stops[i][1]
    number_passenger_per_stop.append(resta)
print(number_passenger_per_stop)
```

Output:

```
[10, 3, -2, -1, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```